# vb.net loop through and extract info from file

Tags: vb.net, file, loops

I have a file where part of it looks like this:

```
 bank: _nameless.292E.6438 
 player: _nameless.2843.0C10
 companies: 312
```

This is my vb.net file that is meant to loop through and give me the line that starts with bank:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Using sr As New StreamReader(currentfile)
        Dim line As String
        line = sr.ReadToEnd()
        If line.StartsWith(" bank:") Then
            Console.WriteLine(line)
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

However, for some reason, this is not working and doesn't write anything to the console. I have tried it without the if statement and it writes the whole file as expected.

The `bank:` was copied and pasted straight from the text file so this is definately the correct text.

Thanks in advance, Marcus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read each line like this:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
  Using sr As New StreamReader(currentfile)
    While Not sr.EndOfStream()
      Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine
      If line.StartsWith(" bank:") Then
        Console.WriteLine(line)
      End If
    End While
  End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: and yeah, that black space was intentional, it is because the text file is laid out like that

Answer (score 1):

You may skip off Blank space like this,

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
Using sr As New StreamReader(currentfile)
 While Not sr.EndOfStream()
   Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine
   line = line.Trim()    'This will remove any white space before and after in the line
   If line.StartsWith("bank:") Then
     Console.WriteLine(line)
   End If
 End While
End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

If line.StartsWith("bank:") Then
        Console.WriteLine(line)
      End If